# If the screen was not touched or has remained inactive for a particular time interval, then do something

Tags: android, touch

I wish to do something(call a function), if for a particular time interval the screen wasn't touched or  was remained inactive.
        How can I achieve this in Android?

Any suggestions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can send a delayed message to the handler of UI thread in `onResume()` method:

```
handler.sendEmptyMessageDelayed(SCREEN_INACTIVE_MSG, DELAY_MILIS);
```

Then, in onTouchEvent remove the message and insert it again:

```
handler.removeMessages(SCREEN_INACTIVE_MSG);
handler.sendEmptyMessageDelayed(SCREEN_INACTIVE_MSG, DELAY_MILIS);
```

In your handler, override `handleMessage()` method, to handle the message:

```
public void handleMessage (Message msg) {
    switch(msg.what) {
        case SCREEN_INACTIVE_MSG:
            handleIdleScreenMetohd();
            break;
    }
}
```

Also, remove the message from the handler in `onPause()`.

This assumes that your activity is active for the whole time (not paused etc.). Handling screen inactivity outside of your app seems impossible.